# How to revert a Windows 8.1 Refresh operation?

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-8-refresh

A relatives Windows 8.1 system performed a Refresh for some reason.

Now there is a file on the desktop listing the apps that were removed, the wallpaper is missing and several files and data.

There is a *c:\windows.old* folder.

Is there a way to undo the whole story?

If not, what can be recovered and how?

Answer (score 0):

> s there a way to undo the whole story?

It is not possible to revert to the previous installation of Windows 8.1

> If not, what can be recovered and how?

You should be able to simply copy and paste any files from within the `Windows.old` directory.  Traditional Win32 desktop applications will have to be reinstalled.

Any files that are not located in the current installation nor within directory contained within windows.old` can be recovered through traditional file recovery software.  File recovery is not guaranteed at this point, the more data you write to the disk, the chances of files being recovered decrease.